# create windows 10 app with wpf

Tags: wpf, windows, pdf, uwp

I have a simple question : **Is it possible to create a windows 10 app (tablet for my case) in WPF instead of UWP ?** Because actually my app need a framework that allow to create pdf, but none free framework exist in UWP yet, but un WPF this is quite different. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF apps are fully supported on Windows 10, so nothing stops you from using WPF instead of UWP!

In fact, you can even take advantage of UWP features in WPF apps by using the [Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root) (Centennial)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: The VisualStudio 2017 can make a wpf app.[Visual Studio 2017 15.4 Release Notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#WAPPtemplate )